# What "question" is Doyle referring to?

Tags: meaning

In *Sling Blade (1996)*, right after their chit chat in dark forest, Frank and Karl return to home.
Frank and Karl find Doyle speaking to Linda. Doyle says to Linda's family:

> Doyle: The upshot is, I'm gonna be spending a lot more time here. We're gonna all get along
> like a family should. I might even surprise you and pop **the question**. Well.
> I'm gonna get on back over to the job site...lock up some stuff over there.

What "question" is Doyle referring to?

Comment: I think you're way out of your debt with this text. But you could easily have googled ***pop the question***

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Doyle is using the idiom [pop the question](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/pop-the-question), meaning to propose marriage.

Comment: He is speaking to whole family, not single person to propose marriage.

Comment: Irrelevant, @KenJames: he's not proposing marriage, he's saying he might do so. It'll be obvious in context who he's talking about - presumably Linda, from your description.

Comment: Then, presumably informing the family that he's considering proposing to Linda.